# Form with route direction does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form set up with the following code:

```
<h2>Add collaborators to the wiki </h2>

<table> 
<tr> 
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Give Access</th>
</tr>

<tr> 
<%= form_for (@collaboration) do |f| %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <td><%= user.name %></td>
 <td><%= user.email %></td>
 <td> <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>   </td>
 </tr>

  <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
 </table>
 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

And my routes are set up like this:

```
    resources :wikis do
      resources :collaborations
    end
```

And in my controller I defined my variables like this:

```
     def new 
      @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:wiki_id])
      @collaboration = @wiki.collaborations.new
     end
```

But when I visit the page clicking on a link I created

```
  <%= link_to 'Add Collaborator', new_wiki_collaboration_path(@wiki) %>
```

I still get this error:

```
 undefined method `collaborations_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8b6a5a8a00>:0x007f8b67820c90>
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form here just goes to `collaboration_path` which you've not defined.

```
<%= form_for (@collaboration) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

You need to include the wiki

```
<%= form_for ([@wiki, @collaboration]) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @japed that was totally what I was looking for!